# Changing background colour of navigationItem and barButtonItem in iOS 16.2

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I just need to change the background colour of navigationItem and barButtonItem in my app.

I have tried so many methods in stack overflow but none of them worked.
I have also tried in my storyboard by using UserDefinedRunTimeAttributes by giving key path as background colour but that also didn't work.[image]

I need an background colour for this navigationItem and their you can see an **save** UIBarButtonItem, also I need on that a background colour and to be bended with some corner radius.

Comment: Update your question with some relevant code that you've tried. Show an example of the actual result you want versus what you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to create your custom view and add your modified button in the custom view and add the custom view in the UIBarButtonItem. That worked for me totally!

```
            let button = UIButton(type: .system)
            button.frame = customView.bounds
            button.setTitle("Logout", for: .normal)
            button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
            button.backgroundColor = .blue
            button.layer.cornerRadius = 12
            // Add the UIButton to the custom view
            customView.addSubview(button)

            // Create a UIBarButtonItem with the custom view
            let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: customView)
            let logoutBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: customView)
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem  = logoutBarButtonItem
```

[image]